# How to reduce lag on FTP upload?

Tags: c++, upload, ftp

So here's my question. C++. I'm currently trying to reduce lag which occurs when application uploads file to remote FTP server, but I don't know where to start.

```
    void upload()
    {   
        HINTERNET hint,hftp;
        hint = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
        hftp = InternetConnect(hint, "hostname", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "username", "password", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
        FtpPutFile(hftp, "C:\\file.dat", "servername.dat", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
        InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
        InternetCloseHandle(hint);
        return;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you have multiple files you could maybe do them in parallel, which technically will not reduce the lag but may allow the files to get there sooner. You could also spawn a background thread or process to do the transfer so your main program can get on with servicing the user's other requests and therefore appear more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the quality of your internet connection with a program. Or you haven't tell us all informations we need to answer to your question ?